# jquery datepicker count special days

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to count the days between two datepickers 
example:

- first datepicker = 12.12.2014
- second datepicker = 20.12.2014
- complete days = 8

That works fine for me. now I want to count three different things.

- complete days
- days in season (special days)
- days not in season (not special days)

example:

- special days are 15 and 16.12.2014
- first date = 12.12.2014 and second day 20.12.2014

I want to display:

- all days = 8
- special days = 2
- not special days = 6

I have made an array for my special days (Thats also a problem, because I have a big list of special days and I don't want to write a very large array. I think it was better like special days are (10.12. - 10.01, 10.05 - 25.05, 30.05 - 15.09) , so they are correctly displayed in datepicker but I don't get these days out of it.

I hope you could understand my problem

here is my code:

```
$ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function() {

    var events = [
        '2014-12-02',
        '2014-12-07',
        '2014-12-15',
        '2014-12-30',
    ];

    $("#Anreise").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+1Y+6M',
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Erfasse ausgewaehltes Datum
            //$("#Abreise").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0'); // Mindestdatum von Abreise auf den Anreisetag gesetzt (Kann angepasst werden)
        },

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var formated_date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

            if ($.inArray(formated_date, events) !== -1) {
                return [true, 'saison', 'Hauptsaison'];
            }
            return [true, '', 'Nebensaison'];
        }



    }); // $("#Anreise").datepicker

    $("#Abreise").datepicker({
        minDate: '0',
        maxDate: '+1Y+6M',
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Erfasse ausgewaehltes Datum
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', max || '+1Y+6M'); // Kann beliebig gesetzt werden (Momentan maximal 18 Monate im vorraus)
            var start = $("#Anreise").datepicker("getDate");
            var end = $("#Abreise").datepicker("getDate");
            var days = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

            $("#Gesamt").html(days);



        },

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var formated_date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

            if ($.inArray(formated_date, events) !== -1) {
                return [true, 'saison', 'Hauptsaison'];
            }
            return [true, '', 'Nebensaison'];
        }
    }); // $("#Abreise").datepicker 
}); // $( document ).ready(function()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it neatly with momentjs - https://github.com/moment/moment 
combined with moment-range - https://github.com/gf3/moment-range

What you could do is define a list of ranges that contain special days. Then get the dates from datepickers and create a range object.

After that you could call intersect with each special days range in a loop, add those together and you would have total special days in your Date picked range. To get the normal days you could simply substract special days from all days.

Basic example showing all needed momentjs and moment-range functions:

```js
$(function(){
  var datepickerRange = moment().range(new Date(2014, 9, 16), new Date(2015, 3, 20));
  var specialRangeFullyInside = moment().range(new Date(2014, 12, 16), new Date(2014, 12, 26));
  var specialRangePartiallyInside = moment().range(new Date(2014, 9, 10), new Date(2014, 9, 18));

  var daysIntersect1 = datepickerRange.intersect(specialRangeFullyInside);
  daysIntersect1 = daysIntersect1 !== null ? daysIntersect1.diff("days") : 0;
  var daysIntersect2 = datepickerRange.intersect(specialRangePartiallyInside);
  daysIntersect2 = daysIntersect2 !== null ? daysIntersect2.diff("days") : 0;

  console.log("10 day special range inside: " + daysIntersect1);
  console.log("8 day special range overlaps 2 days: " + daysIntersect2);
  console.log("Total days: " + datepickerRange.diff("days"));
  console.log("Total special days in range: " + (daysIntersect1 + daysIntersect2));
  console.log("Total normal days in range: " + (datepickerRange.diff("days") - daysIntersect1 - daysIntersect2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-range/1.0.5/moment-range.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. that looks good. but i want to add the dates in the full range dynamicly. i have took and modified your code. but it doesn't work. i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'diff' of null". i have made an exampe on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/1bejtvxv/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: intersect function returns `null` when date ranges do not overlap. I've edited the answer so that is taken into account

Comment: I've edited your jsfiddle and it seems to be working better now: http://jsfiddle.net/1bejtvxv/2/ Not sure whether got the numbers in proper places - don't know german ;)

Comment: I thank you soooo much! :) i have search to understand the "null" problem, but now i can see it :)

Comment: puuuh, it's me again :(. One special date range is 19. december - 05. january. But if I select a date like 29. december - 05. january, I get a negative result. I think it's because the daterange calculate  reverse? Is it because i want to add the year dynamicly? But I don't want to change the code every year manually. p.s. the documentation of moment-range doesn't help me.

Comment: If its negative then you put start date later then end date. You can do it easily dynamically - just make the end date year +1 compared to start date for any ranges that enter the new year :o